# What vectors and attack surfaces do we consider when creating an attack tree for applications hosted on AWS resources?

Tags: attacks, cloud-computing, attack-vector, aws

When illustrating an attack tree for web and mobile applications hosted on AWS resources what vectors do we include. To start out I can include taking over a sub domain using S3 and EC2.

I have gone through these as an aid to get started:

https://downloads.cloudsecurityalliance.org/initiatives/top_threats/The_Notorious_Nine_Cloud_Computing_Top_Threats_in_2013.pdf

https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/#security

Comment: This was also posted on Quora:

https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-vectors-and-attack-surfaces-do-we-consider-when-creating-an-attack-tree-for-applications-hosted-on-AWS-resources